# jQuery (and all #links) Breaks When I Make Container/Parent Div .fadeIn on pageload - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fade

Thanks in advance for your help.

So I have a fully functioning page, but when I make the following changes, my jQuery accordion stops working on rollover and all of my navigation links (which point to #sections as it's a single-page scrolling site) stop working completely. Here is the deadly code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fadeDiv').fadeIn(3000);
    });

    });
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<DIV ID="fadeDiv" style="display:none;"> 
... page here ...
</div>
</body>
```

All functionality which breaks is WITHIN the fadeDiv. It's worth noting that the links (a href="#section") can be IN a div that fades in and will work fine, but will break if, rather, I fade in the containing div of #section.

Weird.

Comment: why `$(document).ready()` twice ?

Comment: Do you have a page we can look at? What part of the accordion stops working? What happens when you click on a link in the accordion?

Comment: Why are you nesting two `$(document).ready(function(){` ?

Comment: Did you call the Jquery library file?

Comment: Are you using jQuery's UI accordion or another plugin?

Answer (score -1):

why are you calling the document ready 2?

Does the jquery file pulled in?

your code should look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fadeDiv').fadeIn(3000);

});
</script>
```

and add this to your header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and i would recomend putting the display none in css

Comment: If the fadeIn is working then he's obviously loading the library. And nesting doc-ready functions is not the issue here.

Comment: it was just a guess, thanks for the minus give me a nother one ;)